# Tate's conjecture and symmetry of Hodge-Tate weights

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, etale-cohomology, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

I'm reading Bellaiche's notes on the Block-Kato conjecture (Hawaii summer school). Here is the link http://people.brandeis.edu/~jbellaic/BKHawaii5.pdf

At page 10 he claims that an indirect consequece of Tate's conjecture is a symmetry for the Hodge-Tate weights of a p-adic representation coming from geometry.

Could anybody explain to me how the implication works?

Thank you.